# positioning issue with translate3d per javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

im working on a little project of mine and noticed a wiered problem.

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4Txr/3/).

If you refresh the fiddle and go to the page **"list"** and then to **"Angebot"** you will notice, that the "old page" slides down correctly but the new page slides up instead of down. In my javascript i position the new page correctly right before the animation. somehow the positioning is not performed before the animation.

And here is the positioning part:

```
if ((activePage.index() + 1) > newPageIndex) {

    move = pageSize;

} else {

    move = -pageSize;
}

newActivePage.css({
    "-webkit-transition-duration": "0",
    "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(0, " + -move + "px, 0)",
    "-moz-transition-duration": "0",
    "-moz-transform": "translate3d(0, " + -move + "px, 0)",
    "transition-duration": "0",
    "transform": "translate3d(0, " + -move + "px, 0)"
});

activePage.css({
    "-webkit-transition-duration": "0.4s",
    "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(0, " + move + "px, 0)",
    "-moz-transition-duration": "0.4s",
    "-moz-transform": "translate3d(0, " + move + "px, 0)",
    "transition-duration": "0.4s",
    "transform": "translate3d(0, " + move + "px, 0)"
}).removeClass("page-active");

newActivePage.css({
    "-webkit-transition-duration": "0.4s",
    "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(0, 0, 0)",
    "-moz-transition-duration": "0.4s",
    "-moz-transform": "translate3d(0, 0, 0)",
    "transition-duration": "0.4s",
    "transform": "translate3d(0, 0, 0)"
}).addClass("page-active");
```

the newActivePage should be positioned on top of the activePage or below depending on the move variable. after that it should be animated accordingly. as i said, for some reason the positioning does not happen before the animation.

Maybe someone knows a solution or workaround.

Thanks in advance
arkhon

EDIT:

unfortunatily the offSetWidth fix only works in chrome but not in firefox.
So maybe someone has any additional ideas?

Comment: Which version of firefox you are using. Its works perfectly on my firefox version 23.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to force the page to render the first set of style for the new page, using `newActivePage[0].offsetWidth;`

You function looks like this,

```
function slidePage(pageSize, newPageIndex, animSpd) {
    var activePage = $(".page-active");
    var newActivePage = $(".pages-wrapper").children(":nth-child(" + newPageIndex + ")");
    var move;

    if ((activePage.index() + 1) > newPageIndex) {

        move = pageSize;

    } else {

        move =- pageSize;
    }

    newActivePage.css({
        "-webkit-transition-duration": "0",
        "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(0, " + -move + "px, 0)",
        "-moz-transition-duration": "0",
        "-moz-transform": "translate3d(0, " + -move + "px, 0)",
        "transition-duration": "0",
        "transform": "translate3d(0, " + -move + "px, 0)"
    });
    newActivePage[0].offsetWidth;
    activePage.css({
        "-webkit-transition-duration": "0.4s",
        "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(0, " + move + "px, 0)",
        "-moz-transition-duration": "0.4s",
        "-moz-transform": "translate3d(0, " + move + "px, 0)",
        "transition-duration": "0.4s",
        "transform": "translate3d(0, " + move + "px, 0)"
    }).removeClass("page-active");

    newActivePage.css({
        "-webkit-transition-duration": "0.4s",
        "-webkit-transform": "translate3d(0, 0, 0)",
        "-moz-transition-duration": "0.4s",
        "-moz-transform": "translate3d(0, 0, 0)",
        "transition-duration": "0.4s",
        "transform": "translate3d(0, 0, 0)"
    }).addClass("page-active");

}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/L4Txr/4/. Its working fine now.

Comment: @arkhon Can i know on which version of firefox its not working ?

Comment: yeah sure. i also use 23.0.1. Firefox shows really wiered behavior. The fiddle works for the first few link clicks. after some random clicks die positioning is off again. confirmed it with the fiddle and locally. Chrome, IE10, Mobile Chrome, Android Stock Browser, and Mobile Firefox all work perfekt.